# # and ## in macros

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringification

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #define f(a,b) a##b
  #define g(a)   #a
  #define h(a) g(a)

  int main()
  {
    printf("%s\n",h(f(1,2)));
    printf("%s\n",g(f(1,2)));
    return 0;
  }
```

Just by looking at the program one "might" expect the output to be, the same for both the printf statements. But on running the program you get it as:

```
bash$ ./a.out
12
f(1,2)
bash$
```

Why is it so?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Because that is how the preprocessor works.

A single '#' will create a string from the given argument, regardless of what that argument contains, while the double '##' will create a new token by concatenating the arguments.

Try looking at the preprocessed output (for instance with `gcc -E`) if you want to understand better how the macros are evaluated.

Comment: I think the question is more about how `h(f(1,2))` and `g(f(1,2))` differ. In that sense @joe-bloggs answer is more clear.

Comment: Hi, what if `#define STR "AAA "`
`#define f(a) (STR#a)`

will `f(BBB)` be `"AAA ""BBB"` or `"AAA BBB"`?  Can this single `#` in middle of strings concatenate arguments?

Answer (score 50):

An occurrence of a parameter in a function-like macro, unless it is the operand of `#` or `##`, is expanded before substituting it and rescanning the whole for further expansion. Because `g`'s parameter *is* the operand of `#`, the argument is not expanded but instead immediately stringified (`"f(1,2)"`). Because `h`'s parameter *is not* the operand of `#` nor `##`, the argument is first expanded (`12`), then substituted (`g(12)`), then rescanning and further expansion occurs (`"12"`).

Answer (score 35):

Below are some related concepts to your question:

[Argument Prescan](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Argument-Prescan.html#Argument-Prescan):

> Macro arguments are completely macro-expanded ***before*** they are
> substituted into a macro body, unless they are ***stringified*** or ***pasted***
> with other tokens. After substitution, the entire macro body,
> including the substituted arguments, is scanned ***again*** for macros to be
> expanded. The result is that the arguments are scanned twice to expand
> macro calls in them.

[Stringification](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-3.0.1/cpp_3.html#SEC17)

> When a macro parameter is used with a leading ‘#’, the preprocessor
> replaces it with the literal text of the actual argument, converted to
> a ***string constant***.

`#ABC => "ABC"`   <---- Note the enclosing double quote, which is added by the stringification process.

[Token Pasting / Token Concatenation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Concatenation.html):

> It is often useful to merge two tokens into one while expanding
> macros. This is called ***token pasting*** or ***token concatenation***. The ‘##’
> preprocessing operator performs token pasting. When a macro is
> expanded, the two tokens on either side of each ‘##’ operator are
> combined into a single token, which then replaces the ‘##’ and the two
> original tokens in the macro expansion.

So the detailed process of your scenario is like this:

```
h(f(1,2))
-> h(12) // f(1,2) pre-expanded since there's no # or ## in macro h
-> g(12)  // h expanded to g
"12"   // g expanded as Stringification

g(f(1,2))
-> "f(1,2)"  //f(1,2) is literally strigified because of the `#` in macro g. f(1,2) is NOT expanded at all.
```