# Spi driver macros

Tags: driver, spi

I cannot understand the macros logic and the way they work...so I can make a `mcp2515_init()` function. If someone can explain I would be glad to listen,thanks for your time.

```
#define true    1
#define false   0

#define True    1
#define False   0

typedef _Bool bool;



#define RESET(x)        _XRS(x)
#define SET(x)          _XS(x)
#define TOGGLE(x)       _XT(x)
#define SET_OUTPUT(x)   _XSO(x)
#define SET_INPUT(x)    _XSI(x)
#define IS_SET(x)       _XR(x)

#define PORT(x)         _port2(x)
#define DDR(x)          _ddr2(x)
#define PIN(x)          _pin2(x)

#define _XRS(x,y)   PORT(x) &= ~(1<<y)
#define _XS(x,y)    PORT(x) |= (1<<y)
#define _XT(x,y)    PORT(x) ^= (1<<y)

#define _XSO(x,y)   DDR(x) |= (1<<y)
#define _XSI(x,y)   DDR(x) &= ~(1<<y)

#define _XR(x,y)    ((PIN(x) & (1<<y)) != 0)

#define _port2(x)   PORT ## x
#define _ddr2(x)    DDR ## x
#define _pin2(x)    PIN ## x
```

Answer (score 0):

I will try to break it down, what you have is a set of bit manipulating macros flipping/setting/clearing one bit on a port they are a generic kind of macros and not specific to the SPI driver.

**bit clear (reset)**

```
#define _XRS(x,y)   PORT(x) &= ~(1<<y)
```

AND port with every bit expect bit `y` on port `x`.

**bit set**

```
#define _XS(x,y)    PORT(x) |= (1<<y)
```

OR port with only bit y set. This will set bit `y` and leave other unaffected.

**toggle**

```
#define _XT(x,y)    PORT(x) ^= (1<<y)
```

XOR a bit with 1 will toggle its value 0 will keep its state.

**This list of macros only take one argument**

```
#define RESET(x)        _XRS(x)
#define SET(x)          _XS(x)
#define TOGGLE(x)       _XT(x)
#define SET_OUTPUT(x)   _XSO(x)
#define SET_INPUT(x)    _XSI(x)
#define IS_SET(x)       _XR(x)
```

so these macros does not look compatible with the as they take one parameter instead of two, but with the magic of macros it is possible to create an output of `x,y` for instance

```
#define GPIO1_PIN4 1,4
#define POWER_LED GPIO0,PIN2
```

will make  `SET(POWER_LED);` a legal assignment.

**The `#` and `##` macros**

```
#define _port2(x)   PORT ## x
```

Are used to concatenate outputs from macros to create new structures [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4364971/and-in-macros)

So using all the macros `_XT(2,15);` will expand to

```
PORT2 = PORT2 ^ (1<<15)
```

*I am personally not a fan of this kind of macros as it breaks how plain vanilla C works by hiding the assignments inside the macros, for instance this style cannot set multiple bits on the same port with single write. However it is legal C and it is common among some embedded systems development environments.*

*It would probably be easier to ignore the above macros and just write the configuration and data directly to the registers word by word.*